# How can I configure ServiceStack Json Serializer to write bool values as int or byte?

Tags: servicestack, jsonserializer

```
 public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive {get;set;}
    }
```

It is serialized as {"Name":"Test1","IsActive":false}

But target serialization result is {"Name":"Test1","IsActive":0}

PS: I can use shorten Property Names via DataContract. But this is value side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just specify the SerializeFn for bool, e.g:

```
JsConfig<bool>.SerializeFn = value => value ? "1" : "0";
```

Comment: Do I have to write deserialize also JsConfig<bool>.DeSerializeFn = c => c=="1";